MUi textfiled with in mui Data grid cell it not working when user enter value getting disappearing
The following link has a live example
Link to live example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ashok-reddy?file=muidatagrid.tsx,index.html,index.tsx.
When user enter value of Mui textfiled with in a mui data grid cell then the enter value getting disappearing after cursor moved from the filed
The following screenshot where user enter value
enter image description here
The following screenshot shows where value was disappear after moved from the filed
enter image description here
MUi textfiled with in mui Data grid cell it not working when user enter value getting disappearing and render function not rendering the React hook form field when user enter value. Therefore user enter value getting disappear after moved out from mui text filed  with mui data grid cell

This is the link for live example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ashok-reddy?file=muidatagrid.tsx,index.html,index.tsx.

=> The main issue lies in the CountButton function. The TextField inside CountButton was controlled by the form's Controller, but its value was not correctly synced with the DataGrid row state.
Modify your CountButton to this:
  const CountButton = (params: GridRenderCellParams<any, string>) => {
    const { id, value } = params.row;

    return (
      <FormControl sx={{ marginTop: 2, width: '100%' }}>
        <Controller
          control={control}
          name="value"
          render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value: fieldValue, ref } }) => (
            <TextField
              id={`value${id}`}
              inputRef={ref}
              onBlur={onBlur}
              onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
                setValue(`value`, e.target.value);
                onChange(e.target.value);
              }}
              value={fieldValue || value} // Display the field value if present, else display the row value
            />
          )}
        />
      </FormControl>
    );
  };

Now, We're using the id and value from the params.row object to access the row's ID and value.
Then render the TextField with the fieldValue obtained from useForm if it's present. If fieldValue is empty, we display the original value from the row.
For my demonstration purposes, I have removed sx property from CountButton function but you can add it for styling purposes later on.
Let me know, If you've any other questions :(

Thank you for your best solution one thing here is when enter value as 'ashok' then if do back space to clear the enter value it was cleared whole value 'ashok' but i want to clear like if enter value as ashok then when i do backspace it should suppose to clear  last character k only instead of clear all clear single single character based on backspace? can we achieve that ? please help me?

...I found one more issue that whenever we change the value it is not being triggering the onchange event  onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent) => {
setValue(value, e.target.value);
alert('tets');
onChange(e.target.value);
}} Even i put alret not tiggering? why so ? i've updated same thing same in code as well can you please verify that?

? any idea for above ask?
